# IdentitySever with SPA Site CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, cors, identityserver3

I've a asp core angular 2 SPA website which authenticates with oidc client to IdenityServer.

I try the spa auth from the [javascript walthrough example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/JavaScript%20Walkthrough) out.

To simulate different domains the spa site runs on `http://localhost:5000` the identityserver on  `http://localhost:7890`

In IdentityServer I added `AllowedCorsOrigins` to the client config.

```
AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
{
     "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

But still I get a crossdomain issue issue when i trigger the redirect

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:7890/identity-server/.well-known/openid-configuration.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The response had HTTP status code 404.

That is probably the most significant part of the error message. You've enabled CORS, but presumably only for pages which actually exist.

You got the URL wrong.

Comment: yeah. i didn't completly realized it. the subpart "identity-server" isn't part of the identityserver url. that fixed it